# Not seeing any output on the screen using REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack

I am not seeing any output on the screen, but I am also not getting any errors. I will post what I can think of being needed. I am starting a new project and trying things a little differently so some help is needed.

**Update:** Here is how I launch the app. I run `npm run server` in the console from root directory and this is the script `"server": "nodemon --watch server --exec babel-node -- server/index.js"`

webpack.config:

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    path.join(__dirname, './client/index.js')
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: '/',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        loaders: [ 'react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js']
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <scrip src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></scrip>
  </body>
</html>
```

App:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>!Hello from react!</h1>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Server index.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config.dev';

const app = express();

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
  hot: true,
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  noInfo: true
}));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: You can't see anything in console?

Comment: Nothing is shown in the console or terminal completely blank on localhost:3000. Let me add server index.js to see if it helps.

Comment: mmm maybe it's a problem on how you launch it. Explain how you did it

Comment: Added how I launch it at the top

Comment: Try changing this app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

To
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

Comment: Did not help, I can't figure out if this is a webpack problem or what. It would help if I had errors but none are shown. =/

Comment: I think the issue is that you've set your `output.path` in your Webpack config to `'/'`. This is [the output directory as an *absolute path*](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-path).

Try setting it to `path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets')` as recommended by the docs -- hopefully this will fix your problem!

Comment: You should run your react app independently from your server..only if you don't do SSR..the react  part looks ok..

Comment: if you just start with React use https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app  

Fix this typo first  
`<scrip src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></scrip>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in `<scrip src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></scrip>`

`<script>` instead `<scrip>`